# Interpreting Scala from a String inside a Spark session

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to interpret a string containing Scala code from inside a Spark session.  Everything is working fine, *except* for User Defined Function-like things (UDFs, map, flatMap, etc).

There are a few references to this problem across the web, and the answers are usually make sure spark-something-or-other is marked as provided in sbt.  This kind of solution doesn't apply here.  Run each of the below examples from a spark-shell:

**Preamble:**

```
import scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerSettings
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain

val settings = new GenericRunnerSettings( println _ )
settings.usejavacp.value = true
val interpreter = new IMain(settings, new java.io.PrintWriter(System.out))
interpreter.bind("spark", spark);
```

**These work:**

```
// works:
interpreter.interpret("val x = 5")

// works:
interpreter.interpret("import spark.implicits._\nval df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(\"foo\",\"bar\")).toDF.show")

// works:
val upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase
spark.udf.register("myUpper", upper)
interpreter.interpret("import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._\nimport spark.implicits._\nval upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase\nval upperUDF = udf(upper)\nspark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(\"foo\",\"bar\")).toDF.withColumn(\"UPPER\", callUDF(\"myUpper\", ($\"value\"))).show")
```

**These do not work:**

```
// doesn't work, fails with seq/RDD serialization error:
interpreter.interpret("import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._\nimport spark.implicits._\nval upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase\nval upperUDF = udf(upper)\nspark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(\"foo\",\"bar\")).toDF.withColumn(\"UPPER\", upperUDF($\"value\")).show")

// doesn't work, fails with seq/RDD serialization error:
interpreter.interpret("import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._\nimport spark.implicits._\nval upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase\nspark.udf.register(\"myUpper\", upper)\nspark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(\"foo\",\"bar\")).toDF.withColumn(\"UPPER\", callUDF(\"myUpper\", ($\"value\"))).show")
```

**The not-working ones fail with this exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2237)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is appreciated!